# Why are 16th notes in groups of 3 not adding up to 4/4?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, rhythm, tuplet

So whats up with the last measure?
It seems that the last two notes are too much.
There are already 4 times 4 1/16 notes?

[image]

It's a piece from Bach; BWV 597

Comment: Need more info. Composer/title/period? Does look like it's gone into 5/4 but forgotten to tell the bass line. Wonder if the next bar's in 3/4...

Comment: Next bar is 4/4 again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pitches were correct - but the beaming was wrong and the tuplets omitted entirely
[image: The pitches were correct - but the beaming was wrong and the tuplets omitted entirely.]

Comment: And this is why un-notated triplets (most common with eighth-note triplets) will come back and bite you in the butt some day.